# in mongodb should i create two collections or one if i have one large string field

Tags: database-design, mongodb

Here is a simplified outline of the actual case,

If I have the following 4 fields i.e. name, picture, bio-text, bio-html.

Question: Should I have 2 collections i.e. users-only and users-with-bio or should i have only one collection i.e. users-with-bio

Usage pattern: Given that a lot of the times I only want the name & picture so querying on users-only will get me what i want and when needed i can query on users-with-bio

Note 1: I understand that in the trivial example above, i could just index the name & picture fields so the document is never retrieved but in the real example there are a lot more 'smaller fields' so indexing all of them is not an option.

Note 2: If bio-text is about 500 to 750k and bio-html 750k to 1mb and at any time i would want only text or html but never both, would it then make sense to have 3 collections i.e. users-only, users-with-text and users-with-html ?

Comment: Do you ever want to read from users-only?  I.e. in three collections you mention, would you sometimes read from users-only? or always from users-with-text or users-with-html?

Comment: Yes, I will almost always be reading from users-only and less often from users-with-html

Answer (score 0):

Just keep one collection, and use the projection option to only retrieve the fields that you need upon querying. Don't even thing about optimising this before you've bench marked anything. I doubt you'd find a bit difference.

Comment: From this link https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/mongodb-user/fTzazoVGBUw it seems that limiting fields forces mongodb to do an extra step since it saves data in BSON ...

Comment: Benchmark it, otherwise you're just making unfounded assumptions. Every data has it's own properties, storage wise and access wise.